# Can not access visualstudio online project

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

I (defined as basic user on visualstudio.com) can not see the project I am in project team. I also have admin privileges on the project. On the same collection, I can see other projects that I am involved but not this specific one which I joined last.

Already tried, signing out and back in. Tried accessing via command line git, and from visual studio 2015.

I can access the project with another members token, but not with my own credentials.

Comment: If you navigate to this team project https://xxx.visualstudio.com/gitProjectName/_dashboards from browser directly, will you get any error message? Could you share it?

Comment: @Cece - MSFT
Here is the error message : 
http://pasteboard.co/1d3AIe7m.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TFS uses a least-permissive model for security permissions. What that means is that if a user belongs to two groups and the same permission is assigned Allow for one group and Deny for another group, Deny takes precedence over Allow.

So check the groups that your account belongs to to see whether "**View project-level information**" set to Allow in every group you belong to.

Answer (score 0):

I now have access, here is what I did after @Cece-MSFT 's answer.

I went to the settings section from the other user's account (owner.) From the security tab, I searched for owners ID and my ID, and compared all the memberships.

[image: Security Tab]

After that I removed all my extra memberships (which probably had less priviliges) and added the ones that I didn't have.

[image: Permissions Tab]

Now I can access to the project. Thanks.